# UDIM is not displayed in Version 3.6 (Steam version)

Tags: texturing, uv

I saved a texture in UDIM format and packed it into a blend file, but it does not display. Normal UV is packed and displayed. After I lowered the version to 3.3, the packed UDIM is displayed correctly.

How is it displayed in 3.6?

What I have tried:

- Reinstalled Blender
- Testing UDIM without inheriting environment settings
- Updating GPU drivers